# Using Python to Split Text String into Two Variables

Tags: python

I need to split a text string like this: “Hello Everyone Bye Everyone” into two different variables so “Hello Everyone” is one variable and the other variable is “Bye Everyone” What is the easiest way of doing this? I have been experimenting with maxsplit within the split function but no luck. I put an example of what I’m trying below. Any help or insight would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
message.content.split(' ',maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: What is the general rule where to split the string?

Comment: Also consider providing more positive and negative test cases so we can better understand your intent.

Comment: Consider that, for this example and with no further information, there are essentially infinite ways to do it... including simply `string1, string2 = 'Hello Everyone', 'Bye Everyone'`. A *useful* and *generalized* way to do it requires knowing what "it" is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can something like below in one line with 2 iterations

```
message = "Hello Everyone Bye Everyone"
hello_message, bye_message = [msg + ' Everyone' for msg in message.split(' Everyone') if msg]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to approach the problem by writing a simple function.

```
def split_by_two(line):
    words = line.split(" ")
    words_by_two = [" ".join(line_sp[i: i+2]) for i in range(0, len(line_sp), 2)
    return words_by_two

return split_by_two(message.content)
```

By running this function, the output would be groups of two words in list.

Comment: Provided that's what the asker is trying to do... but we don't know what their actual splitting criterion is.

Comment: Oops! I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, updated, for your problem

You must use `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`, because return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
s = "Hello Everyone Bye Everyone"

a = s.split('Bye', 1)[0]
b = s.split('Everyone', 1)[1]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: @Brandon1419 You forgot to accept my answer as a solution, considering that I answered in time among the first and that my code works correctly and that is what you asked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is always four words split by a single space, you can do something like this:

```
my_string = "Hello Everyone Bye Everyone"

one_str = ' '.join(my_string.split(' ')[0:2])
two_str = ' '.join(my_string.split(' ')[2:])
```